# Java: How to move classes to another package in Idea Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, project-structure

I have the following file sctructure:

`name1/name2/name3/name4 (must be project's root and git root)/src/main/java/com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/init/woodenStone`

Inside the last folder (`woodenStone`) my `.java` files are located.

The IntelliJ Idea makes everything look like this:

```
name4
  src
     main.java.com.fileinside1.fileinside2.fileinside3                             
               init.woodenStone
                      SomeFile1.java
                      SomeFile2.java
```

And inside every file there is a

`package main/java/com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/init/woodenStone;`

as the first line.

So, the files are located in package which starts with `main` folder. But I need the package to be

`com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/init/woodenStone`,

to get a little deeper inside.

So far I only manage to do so by manually changing the package name in .java files, `Alt+Entering` it and selecting "Move to package com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/init/woodenStone".

But I have more than 50 files and would really appreciate a way to do it for all files at once.

Could anyone please tell me if there is such a way?

EDIT: Just found out that even the way I use doesn't really work right. Instead of moving file's into deeer project's folder, Idea just creates a second `com` folder inside `src` (How does it even manage to create a floder with the same name?).

Comment: Just use `sed` or something.

Comment: you can just drag and drop :)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176751/how-to-create-a-sub-package-and-add-existing-files-intellij

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open the *Project* panel and select the *Project* view (top left).
- Make sure that the *main* directory isn't marked as a source root. You may need to unmark it by right clicking and selecting Mark Directory As -> Unmark...)
- Make sure that your *java* directory is marked as a source root (right click, Mark Directory As -> Sources Root).
- Select all the files in the woodenStone directory.
- F6 -> Move Specified Files -> to package

Comment: When I click on `java` directory and then under "Mark Directory As" there is only a "Excluded" option! And it happens for all folders inside `main` (they are not listed in Idea separately too, everything from 'main' to `fileinside3` is on the same line, separated by dots.

Comment: Looks like one of its parent directories is marked as a source root. Find it (it will be blue), and unmark it first.

Comment: Ok, I unmarked a higher folder, then marked `java` as source root and the folders `com/fileinside1/fileinside2` became written on the same line, separated by dots, while folders `fileinside3` and `init` and `woodenStone` are written lower, separately, each at its own line. What should I do now?

Comment: Select all the files you want to move (use shift to make multiple selections), and then hit F6. The dialog it brings up will allow you to change the package.

Comment: When I press F6 it asks me if I want to move selected files to a given deirectory (which is the full path to these files)...

Comment: Are they in a directory under a source root (i.e. the _java_ directory, which should be blue now)?

Comment: Yes. The whole path is `name1/name2/name3/name4 (must be project's root and git root)/src/main/java/com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/init/woodenStone`.

Comment: literally `(must be project's root and git root)`?

Comment: No, that's just a comment which I must obey. And I'm somewhat confused about how to make it a project root, since there is no such option in "Mark directory As".

Comment: When you say "fileinside3 and init and woodenStone are written lower", where exactly do you mean?. It sounds to me like they're not actually in the "fileinside2" directory in the file system.

Comment: I mean that IDEA places them on the lines inder the while `com.fileinside1/fileinside2` thing.

Comment: I just noticed something in your question. Do your package names have slashes in them, like "main/java/com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/init/woodenStone", rather than dots: "main.java.com.fileinside1.fileinside2.fileinside3.init.woodenStone"?

Comment: No, package names have only dots in them.

Comment: I think I fixed that issue now - the property "Flatten packages" was unchecked. But I still can't add all files to the package `com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3/‌​init/woodenStone`, they all still have `package main/java/com/fileinside1/fileinside2/fileinside3` inside.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Let me know if you get it sorted. I'd be interested to know what the problem was.

Comment: Solved it. MyTitle's answer helped me out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944834/how-to-fix-package-names-in-intellij.

Comment: Unmarking `java` folder and moving the classes where I needed, then marking it again as 'Sources root' worked for me